# How to properly rename XCode 6 product name and bundles

Tags: ios, xcode6

I usually do not know the final name of the app I am building, so I start by creating an Xcode 6 project with a internal name - like "Hercules" or something.

Now that I am ready to distribute to the app store I need to rename my project and the two targets (iOS, Mac) bundle name and identifiers.

While I managed to do this, I have a project that cannot run, build, or anything (everything is grayed out).

What is the proper way to do I need?

Comment: In the documentation window in Xcode search for 'Renaming a Project or App' or right click on a target and select it from Project Editor Help and you'll get step by step instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There probably is no "best" answer as each team will want to handle the situation differently. You can either fix the build problems caused by changing the names (in which case you have your solution) or revert back to a buildable version of your project under the codename and change the "bundle display name" in the info.plist for the targets.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also "manage" your build schemes and rename the scheme there which will change the name in other places in Xcode.