# How to change the product name in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 7 `Product Name` defaults to `$(TARGET_NAME)`.

Our target name is `MyTarget` but we'd like Product Name to be `My Product`.

What is the correct way to change `Product Name`?   Is it to change the target name?   Or just remove the `$(TARGET_NAME)` setting and enter `My Product` as the value for `Product Name`?

Or is it completely arbitrary...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly rename XCode 6 product name and bundles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815298/how-to-properly-rename-xcode-6-product-name-and-bundles)

Comment: Can see my question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/38394548/1136253

Answer (score 2):

[image]go to your build settings

seach product Name and change the name you want

Answer (score 0):

You go to Build Settings and change the product name