# Build settings in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

Where is the Build Settings window in Xcode 7 ?

It seems Apple has changed it in new version.
There isn't a menu item named Project in Xcode 7.

Comment: No,its still there.

Comment: I'm trying to change the project name. I heard there is Build Settings / Product Name in old version.

Comment: There is "Product" but "Project" is not exists on my Xcode. I'm using Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: And Product menu does not contain Build settings.

Comment: To rename project Select Project from navigationBar > Select your project  > find Identity and Type at right side of screen (Wiil be your current project name) change it to name you want.

Comment: I have now found the Build Settings, but searching to change the name, just a minute

Comment: will be in property Inspector

Comment: look for  Identity and Type, Change it. You will get a popup to change all relevant names in your project.

Comment: Its okey now, I have changed the project name in that property inspector but because of name has a space, I didn't changed popup's values when asked me for the changes. My aim was to change the name that was seen when I debug the project on iPhone. It have to have space character. Is the name on iPhone also be changed when I change the project name in only property inspector? (I will debug on iPhone again).
I ask this because I didn't have changed the asked popup's values.

Comment: if you just wish to change the name on display screen then find display name property that all you need.

Comment: Please write your fix to answer and I have to approve you. The one for Build settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

To rename project Select Project from navigationBar > Select your project > find Identity and Type at right side of screen (Wiil be your current project name) change it to name you want.

if you just wish to change the name on display screen then find display name property that all you need

Comment: Hope this helped you @mrbrngi

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The build settings are at the top there.